# Telescope Error when I run "meteor add my-custom-package" command

Tags: telescope

I get this error below when I run "meteor add my-custom-package" command, and I am not sure what the problem is.

---

=> Errors while parsing arguments:

While adding package my-custom-package:
error: no such package

Comment: Have you double checked the path?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem while trying to create a private package. I was following guides online and creating all the file manually, a better way is running:

`meteor create --package example`

and then adding the package will work:
`meteor add example`